# Database.getConnection() Error -->Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

Tags: mysql, jdbc, insert

I have developed a  application, which displays the id,subject,indexno and additional information. There are seperate text box for each of the field, whenever the user fills the form and hits submit button the value must be inserted into my database. If I try to submit it to the database nothing is happening. Please look at the following codes.

```
        try {
            Connection con = null;
            PreparedStatement pst = null;
            String id = "", subject = "", indexNo = "", additional = "";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            int updateQuery = 0;
            if (id == null && subject == null && indexNo == null && additional == null) {
                if (id == "" && subject == " " && indexNo == "" && additional == "") {

                    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "KUMAR");

                    String query="insert into circularindex(id,subject,indexNo,additional)values(?,?,?,?)";
                    pst = con.prepareStatement(query);

                    pst.setString(1, id);
                    pst.setString(1, subject);
                    pst.setString(2, indexNo);
                    pst.setString(3, additional);
                    pst.executeUpdate();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Database.getConnection() Error -->" + ex.getMessage());
        }
```

Please help me for above coding error and do the needful.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a typo when you set parameter like:

```
pst.setString(1, id);
pst.setString(1, subject);
pst.setString(2, indexNo);
pst.setString(3, additional);
```

You are setting first parameter twice by overwriting the other. You should do it like

```
pst.setString(1, id);
pst.setString(2, subject);
pst.setString(3, indexNo);
pst.setString(4, additional);
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response but even i tried that too. Still it is not working.

Comment: Can you paste the full stack trace please?

Comment: can you help me . how to add the full stack code in comment or ?

Comment: i am unable to add the full stack details in add comment tab. can you help me where to add the details in stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi Almas shaikh... waiting for your help

Comment: @Jeevetha He told you to add the details into your question, not a comment. Edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a typo which has been already pointed out by almas. If it still exist, try adding it without primary key (just in case if it's a auto gen PK):

```
String query="insert into circularindex(id,subject,indexNo,additional) values (?,?,?)";
pst = con.prepareStatement(query);

pst.setString(1, subject);
pst.setString(2, indexNo);
pst.setString(3, additional);

pst.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some conflicting if statements. The first one tests that all input are null, then the nested if tests if they are all empty. They can't be both.

I removed both if statements and hard-coded some values for the setString arguments. The code works.

It does not seem logical that you want to insert null or empty strings into the database. I think you want to be sure they are **NOT** null and **NOT** empty.

Change the if statements so they test for non null and not empty, add some values to all four strings and you should be able to access the database.